# endure, perdure, persist: why not keep open?

Tags: discussion, on-topic-off-topic, protected-questions

Closure should not necessarily follow Protection, nor should Deletion necessarily follow Closure.  These are three independent steps.

[“endure” vs “perdure” vs “persist”](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/78136/endure-vs-perdure-vs-persist) was protected 23 hours ago, and already has three votes for closure.

It was protected because of VLQ answers, at least one of them very recent.
Fine.

Now the question is on its way to closure because it **looks** like a general reference question.  Forget about the fact that the question was OK by the standards of its time (August 2012).  Read the answers and comments!  Do you understand the subtle difference between perdure and endure?  I don't, nor has some googling of my own made it clear.

The question and the site would benefit from a bit more work on this question.  @tchrist has the priority on this, but if he doesn't want to revisit an antique question, someone else may, this week or next month or sometime.  Possibly me.

The first step after being arrested is not being found guilty and sentenced to prison.  The first step after being protected should not be being closed.

Comment: IMO, I think we need to make a comment to the OP (he seems to have logged in a few hours ago) so that he may edit the question to meet the standards first. We can't deny the fact that the question lacks some research efforts and example sentence that could have made the OP confused. I am not a native English speaker as you know and I found some example sentences with to perdure and there is no confusing about the meaning of to "perdure". It reads like it is 99.9% synonym of to endure. Will there be any other context than mentioned in the answer (philosophy or religion) that require "perdure"?

Comment: @Rathony I just edited the question to bring it into line with the norms of 2016, although I haven't done as good a job as I would like to.  It is 4th of July weekend here!

Comment: One more user voted to close it. I am not sure the question is worth saving. I will let other users decide it as I did what I thought was the right thing to do. Happy July 4th Weekend!

Comment: "Closure should not necessarily follow Protection, nor should Deletion necessarily follow Closure":1st correct, 2nd wrong. Protection is independent from closure, protection to stop stupid answers, closure to stop answering stupid questions. Deletion should eventually follow closure, if activity to reopen it doesn't occur (and not a duplicate) Read the SE faqs

Comment: I retracted my close-vote (it was the third vote) because you edited the question and two low-quality answers were deleted. I posted my answer  but decided to delete it. It's a pity you can't read it now, but you will be able to read it when you reach 10K rep. Hurry up!

Comment: I've made the question "prettier" to look at. Luckily you added the definitions, because the difference between *persist* and *endure* isn't really mentioned anywhere. tchrist's answer focuses on *perdure* and Philosopher's answer explains the difference btw *persist* and *perdure* NOT "endure", which is why I modified your edit to say "It appears the answers and comments ... *blah*... *blah*.... Relying on comments to provide answers is unwise, as comments can be deleted arbitrarily either by their owners or by the mods.

Comment: I waited until the 3 votes for closure had disappeared before editing, so your intervention was a success, well done!

Comment: @Mari-Lou A  Thank you.  It's much better now.

Comment: @Rathony I think the right decision was made to keep the question opened. With a bit of editing, the question became intrinsically useful, helpful, and interesting. worthy of EL&U , and the original two answers are still good answers despite the update. We also have to look at the answers posted on old questions, good answers *must* not be deleted, even if the Q is off-topic by today's standards. A good answer will still be good, three, four, and five years from now.

Comment: I've read in Rathony's deleted answer that is tempted to delete this question: [Correct usage of pronoun: “their” vs “its”](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/5142/correct-usage-of-pronoun-their-vs-its) **What?!** I don't know who the two voters are who cast their close vote, but they are both wrong!

Comment: @Mari-Lou A  I am about 2,000 rep points from the awesome power to delete questions.  If I ever get there, I will delete only pure crap.  This question is very basic, but it has one interesting answer.  I have a problem with deleting questions in general, and particularly with scatter-shot deleting.   And if all the basic questions are deleted, how will the site be representative of English?   The analogy that sticks in my mind is: what if Louis and Mary Leakey had thrown everything that was not a complete skull on the rubbish heap?

Comment: I shudder to think what will happen if you and Rathony becomes allies in your quest to purge every LQ post. Use your *power* for good, not for for feeling important.

Comment: @Mari-Lou A (1) I am very opposed to closing/deleting old Qs/As that met the standard of their day; (2)  I am aggressive about voting to delete current VLQ answers -- usually top of the head one-liners with no references and no insights; (3)  closing current Qs -- I am still developing my philosophy, but I think it is important to look at the quality of the comments and answers in each case, and to remember that the OP is a human being;  (4)  deleting Qs -- if I ever get to 10K rep, I will look at almost any Q (except pure crap) as historical data that might be mined in the future.

Answer (score -3):

Keep in mind that when many of the close votes were cast [this was the extent of the question](https://english.stackexchange.com/revisions/78136/1):

> ## “endure” vs “perdure” vs “persist”
>
> erdure and endure both mean "to remain in existence", and persist means "continue to exist". So are there any differences among the three verbs?

That's how the question was when ab2 started this meta discussion, and in such a state it absolutely deserved to be closed. Neither the age of a question nor community standards at the time it was asked matter in the slightest to determining whether it is up to scratch now.

ab2 has since edited in some definitions, a questionable act to save a questionable question.

IMO it should still be closed. Checking one single online dictionary is not sufficient research effort, especially if that dictionary is not the OED.

Comment: There are two points in this answer: (1) editing the question was a "questionable act to save a questionable question."  (Nice English!) Editing a question to save it is questionable only if one sees a way to garner many rep points by so doing -- and even then, I'm not sure It is necessarily questionable.  Thus I disagree that my act was questionable (i.e., possibly dishonorable).    As for the standards an old question must meet, that is arguable -- it has been argued here on Meta -- my view is that a question has only to meet the standards of its time.  But I won't argue that here.

Comment: @ab2 On every site in the network questions must meet the current standards.

Comment: @ab2 Editing a question in a substantial way without the permission of the OP is always questionable. That's all I meant. It would've been better to close this question and ask a new one.